# Constructible enumerable set

Tags: algorithms, computability, turing-machines, enumeration

We suppose that the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are constructible enumerable, that means that there is an algorithm that enumerates them. Show that the sets $S_1 \cup S_2$ and $S_1 \times S_2$ are also constructible enumerable.

To show this do we have to construct a Turing machine for the union and one for the cartesian product?

Comment: Yes, a Turing Machine which enumerates the union and an other one which enumerate all the pairs. But you can also think with an higher abstraction level.

Comment: You can generate an infinite output stream which enumerates the elements of a set, using infinite input streams of sets that you already know enumerable. This allow you to use pseudo-code rather than Turing Machines.

Comment: You can also write a semi-algorithm (always finishes when output is true) which recognizes the target set using semi-algorithms for other problems already known r.e.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. For $S_1 \cup S_2$, use the same idea in the proof that the natural numbers and the integers have the same cardinality. The proof goes by listing the integers in sequence:
   $$ 0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\ldots $$
   You can think of $S_1$ as $0,1,2,3,\ldots$ and of $S_2$ as $-1,-2,-3,\ldots$.
2. For $S_1 \times S_2$, use the same idea in the proof that the natural numbers and the positive rationals have the same cardinality. The proof uses the "diagonal method", and consists of listing the rationals sorted by the maximum of the numerator and the denominator:
   $$ \frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{1}, \frac{2}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{3}, \ldots $$
   In this case $S_1=S_2$ are both $1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: Nice hint but the question wasn't about the enumerators themselves, but about their type (TM or not ?) !

Comment: @FrançoisGodi Yes, I realize that. Fortunately, the proofs of the results I mention are effective, i.e., they result in an algorithm for solving the exact problems which the OP is after.

Comment: Could you explain to me further how we enumerate the cartesian product? I haven't really understood it... @YuvalFilmus

Comment: You'll have to keep thinking...

Answer (score 1):

One way to show that a set is enumerable, is to provide a TM that enumerates all the words in that set. (that what the comments are trying to say, and probably what you are asking)

A second way is to show a bijection to another enumerable set of the same cardinality (like the natural numbers or like $S_1$ or $S_2$ themselves, in case they are infinite.) This is what  Yuval was trying to hint.

Choose your way, both are correct.

Comment: I will try using the first way: $S_1$ is enumerable so there are the TM $M_1=(F_1, \Sigma , \delta_1 , s_1 , H_1)$ and $M_2=(F_2, \Sigma , \delta_2 , s_2 , H_2)$ that enumerate all the words in the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively. 

We construct a TM $M_u=(F_u, \Sigma, \delta_u, s_u, H_u)$ that enumerates all the words in the set $S_1 \cup S_2$, where $F_u=F_1 \cup F_2$, $s_u=s_1$, $H_u=H_1 \cup H_2$. But how will the transition function $\delta_u$ look like??

Comment: Or didn't you mean to provide a TM in that way??

Comment: @MaryStar right, it is not immediate. You need to run them "in parallel". Just think how to "interleave" the two machines: one word from $M_1$ then one word from $M_2$, then another from $M_1$, etc...

Comment: So, do we have to describe the TM $M_u$ in words?? Does the TM $M_u$ looks as followed?? When we start with a word of $M_1$ we have at the even numbered tape squares of $M$ words of the $M_2$ and at the odd numbered tape squares words of $M_1$. Is this correct??

Comment: Then Alice asked: "do we have to describe the TM $M_u$ in words"?, and the the Cheshire cat answered "Where do you want to go?". I don't care if you describe it by words, or give the full $\delta_u$; both are doable and correct in my eyes; this depends on *your* goals. 
About the tapes: for me it would be most convenient to use multiple tapes: two for $M_1$ (work/output), two for $M_2$, and one for the output of the combined enumerator.

Comment: Could you explain to why we should use two tapes for $M_1$ and two for $M_2$??

Comment: One as a working tape, the other as output tape, where the machine enumerates the output words. This may depend on the specific definition of enumerator you use, but it is just more convenient. If the same tape is used for work and output, then it is more difficult to combine the two machines - since $M_1$ expects that the tape entirely belongs to it, and so does $M_2$. Anyways, these are not very important subtleties. If you need more clarification, let's move this discussion the [chat].

Comment: I invited you at a chat, because I want some more clarifications...